# FFmpeg wrong duration(double) when convert mp4

Tags: ffmpeg

The output file has the double duration :

Source video duration :00:01:58.88

output video duration :00:03:57.76

（video's duration is double ，audio's duration is correct. So， the video looks like played twice, with no sound in the second half ）

here is the log：

./ffmpeg -i /Volumes/LANKEXIN/1383.mp4  out.mp4
ffmpeg version N-82977-g8fd3e02-tessus Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-version3 --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=qtkit --disable-indev=x11grab_xcb

```
  libavutil      55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavcodec     57. 70.100 / 57. 70.100
  libavformat    57. 61.100 / 57. 61.100
  libavdevice    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
  libavfilter     6. 68.100 /  6. 68.100
  libswscale      4.  3.101 /  4.  3.101
  libswresample   2.  4.100 /  2.  4.100
  libpostproc    54.  2.100 / 54.  2.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Volumes/LANKEXIN/1383.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2017-10-30T14:58:05.000000Z
    encoder         : mp4creator 1.6.1d
  Duration: 00:01:58.88, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1918 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1729 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-10-30T14:58:05.000000Z
      encoder         : VC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 189 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-10-30T14:58:05.000000Z
File 'out.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] 264 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2016 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'out.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isom
    encoder         : Lavf57.61.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-10-30T14:58:05.000000Z
      encoder         : Lavc57.70.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-10-30T14:58:05.000000Z
      encoder         : Lavc57.70.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   46 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.93 bitrate=   0.0kbits/sframe=   64 fps= 45 q=28.0 size=     137kB time=00:00:01.66 bitrate= 672.2kbits/frame=   85 fps= 44 qframe= 5944 fps= 33 q=-1.0 Lsize=   38746kB time=00:03:57.64 bitrate=1335.7kbits/s speed=1.33x    4kB time=00:00:02.94 bitrate= 818.0kbits/s speed= 1.2x    
video:36779kB audio:1846kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.311413%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] frame I:24    Avg QP:19.49  size: 67090
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] frame P:1806  Avg QP:21.65  size: 14304
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] frame B:4114  Avg QP:25.42  size:  2484
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] consecutive B-frames:  2.2%  8.1% 25.5% 64.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] mb I  I16..4: 20.6% 55.8% 23.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] mb P  I16..4:  5.2%  9.3%  0.8%  P16..4: 36.0%  9.9%  4.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:34.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] mb B  I16..4:  0.5%  1.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 27.2%  1.8%  0.2%  direct: 0.9%  skip:68.5%  L0:48.6% L1:47.6% BI: 3.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] 8x8 transform intra:60.9% inter:78.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 38.3% 61.5% 12.3% inter: 6.6% 11.3% 0.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 22% 35% 10% 33%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 24% 21%  5%  6%  6%  6%  5%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 33% 11%  4%  7%  6%  6%  4%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 43% 30% 20%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.3% UV:0.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] ref P L0: 73.5%  9.0% 13.8%  3.7%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] ref B L0: 92.4%  6.6%  1.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] ref B L1: 97.7%  2.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fbaca003c00] kb/s:1267.21
[aac @ 0x7fbaca021800] Qavg: 897.576
```

Comment: Share the full log.

Comment: I reposted the full log  ,thank you.

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -i /Volumes/LANKEXIN/1383.mp4 -vf setpts=N/50/TB -r 50 out.mp4`